# Insert a blank column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to insert a blank column in between "Delta = delta" and "Card = vars" in the dataframe below.  I would also like to sort the output by the column "Model_Avg_Error" in the dataframe as well.

```
df = data.frame(Card = vars, Model_Avg_Error = model_error, Forecast = forecasts,  Delta = delta, ,Card = vars, Model_Avg_Error = model_error, 
                Forecast = forecasts,  Delta = delta)

# save
write.csv(df, file = file.path(proj_path, "output.csv"), row.names = F)
```

This was the error received from above:

Error in data.frame(Card = vars, Model_Avg_Error = model_error, Forecast = forecasts,  : 
  argument is missing, with no default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add your blank column, re-order, and sort using the code below:

```
df$blankVar <- NA #blank column 
df[c("Card", "blankVar", "Model_Avg_Error", "Forecast", "Delta")] #re-ordering columns by name
df[order(df$Model_Avg_Error),] #sorting by Model_Avg_Error
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general way to add a new, blank column

```
library(tibble)

# Adds after the second column
iris %>% add_column(new_col = NA, .after = 2)

# Adds after a specific column (in this case, after Sepal.Width)
iris %>% add_column(new_col = NA, .after = "Sepal.Width")
```

Comment: It should be `tibble::add_column` now. Check out https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/add_column.html